# Arbitrary close and norm-bounded approximations to an element in a Banach space from a dense subset

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have an element $e \in E$, where $E$ is a Banach space, and $\lVert e\rVert=l$.

I also have a subset $Y$ which is dense in $E$.

Does this mean that we can find element $y\in Y$ s.t. $\lVert y - e\rVert \le \frac{l}{2}$ and $\lVert y\rVert \le l$? If so, why?

I have the feeling that a Banach space is like the Euclidean space $\mathbf R^n$ so to speak continuous and we can find elements arbitrary close to an element.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define "everywhere dense"?

Comment: Every point of $E_y$ is either a point of $E_n$ or it's an accumulation point of $E_n$ i.e. $cl(E_n)=E_y$.

Comment: I understand that, this is in case our y is an accumulation(limit) point. In that case, sure, we can find arbitrarily close elements to our $y$. But what about the case when our point is not an accumulation(limit) point of $Y_n$. Do we just say that the element we can find is just the same element, i.e. $y$?

Comment: But what is $E_n$? Ankd how can $Y_n$ be both an "element" and a set?

Comment: My mistake, I tried to edit my comment but it doesn't let me. $E_n$ was supposed to be $Y_n$. $Y_n$ is everywhere dense in $E_y$ which means that every element of $E_y$ is either of $Y_n$ or it's an accumulation (limit) point of $Y_n$. That is, $cl(Y_n)=E_y$.

Comment: But what about $Y_n$? It's clearly not an "element". So is it a subset of $E_y$? A subspace of $E_y$?

Comment: And by the way, why is the Banach space called $E_y$, rather than simply $E$?

Comment: $Y_n$ is an everywhere dense subset of the Banach space $E_y$. When you close it, you get the whole Banach space $E_y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit fiddly to prove because of the requirement that $\| y \| \leq l$. But I believe it can be done.

Rather than trying to approximate $e$ directly, I'm going to approximate $\frac 3 4 e$. Indeed, this is possible: since $Y$ is dense in $E$, there exists an $y \in Y$ such that

$$ \| y - \tfrac 3 4 e \| < \tfrac l 4.$$

Applying the triangle inequality twice, we have
$$ \| y\| \leq \| y - \tfrac 3 4 e \| + \|\tfrac 3 4 e \| < \tfrac l 4 +\tfrac {3l} 4 = l$$
and
$$ \| y - e \| \leq \| y - \tfrac 3 4 e \| + \| \tfrac 3 4 e - e \| < \tfrac l 4 + \tfrac l 4 = \tfrac l 2.$$

---

**[Added to address point raised in comments]**

It is even possible to find a $y \in Y$ such that $\| y - e \| \leq \frac l 2$ and $\| y \| \leq l$ and $y \neq e$.

We would simply choose a $y \in Y$ that approximates $\tfrac 3 4 e$ even closer, for example, we would choose a $y \in Y$ such that

$$ \| y - \tfrac 3 4 e \| < \tfrac l 8.$$

The previous argument still applies, so we still get $\| y - e \| \leq \frac l 2$, and $\| y \| \leq l$.

And $\| y - \tfrac 3 4 e \| < \tfrac l 8$ also tells us that $y$ cannot possibly be equal to $e$.

Comment: So, when $Y_n$ is dense in $E_y$ we can always find an element $y'$ that is arbitrary close to our element $y$ s.t. $y\neq y'$? I know that every element of $E_y$ is either of $Y_n$ or a limit point of $E_y$. What do we do in the second case? Do we just use the same element $y$ as an approximation?

Comment: @Nikola I've responded to this in the answer.